# Using Link component dynamically in React-Router

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

Depending on a conditional stored in component state, I would like a particular component being rendered to either be wrapped in a `Link` tag or a regular `div` tag (or no tag works just as well!)

What I'm currently doing seems verbose and redudnant; I feel like there's a shorter way I could write this component to keep my code DRY.

Both variables storing my `linkThumbnail` and `defaultThumbnnail` components are pretty much exactly the same, except for the fact that one of them is contained within a `Link` component.

I then use a ternary operator in the `return` statement to give me the desired component.

Here's some pseudocode as an example:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

class ExampleComponent extends Component {
  state = {
    renderLink: false
  };

  render() {
    const linkThumbnail = (
      <Link
        to={{
          pathname: `/someMovieId`,
          state: 'some-data'
        }}
      >
        <div>
          <div className='movie' onClick={this.getMoviePreview}>
            <img
              src={
                poster
                  ? `https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w300${poster}`
                  : "https://via.placeholder.com/300"
              }
              alt='something here'
            />
          </div>
        </div>
      </Link>
    );

    const defaultThumbnail = (
      <div>
        <div className='movie' onClick={this.getMoviePreview}>
          <img
            src={
              poster
                ? `https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w300${poster}`
                : "https://via.placeholder.com/300"
            }
            alt='something here'
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    );

    //here I use a ternary operator to show the correct component...shorter method of doing this?
return this.state.renderLink ? linkThumbnail : defaultThumbnail;
  }
}

export default ExampleComponent;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating another component which gets `this.state.renderLink` as a prop:

```
const ThumbnailLink = ({enabled, children, ...props}) => {
    if (enabled) {
        return <Link {...props}>{children}</Link>;
    } else {
        return <div>{children}</div>;
    }
}

class ExampleComponent extends Component {
    render() {
        return (<ThumbnailLink enabled={this.state.renderLink} to={{pathname: `/someMovieId`, state: 'some-data'}}>
            <div>
                <div className='movie' onClick={this.getMoviePreview}>
                    <img
                        src={
                            poster
                            ? `https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w300${poster}`
                            : "https://via.placeholder.com/300"
                        }
                        alt='something here'
                    />
                </div>
            </div>
        </ThumbnailLink>);
    }
}
```